# How Initialize divs text containers with SlideUp JQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, slideup

I have the next question: In this moment I'm developing a web application, and I'm configuring the forms of my page. However, they are really long, so I decided to create differents divs to implement the JQuery Function: slideUp(); , slideDown(); Nonetheless, every time I reaload my page every div is  slidedown by default. How can I change this? I want every div be SlideUp at the beggining.

This is my JQuery Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var control = 0;
    $(".subtitulo").click(function(){
        var contenido = $(this).attr('data-contenido');
        if(control==0){
            $(".contenidoAcordeon-" + contenido).slideUp("fast");
            control = 1;
        }else{
            $(".contenidoAcordeon-" + contenido).slideDown("fast");
            control = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I can't see your form's html so I'm going to make some assumptions.

You're javascript code only fires when `.subtitulo` is clicked. You could initialize this by using the following to trigger a click event when the script is loaded.

```
$('.subtitulo').trigger('click');
```

But it would be better to hide all but the first div (the one you want shown by default) with css.

```
[class^=contenidoAcordeon-] {
    display: none;
}

[data-contenido=1] { // Guessing you can select your first div this way.
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much Craig, You've solved my problem :) Now it works as I wanted. :D

Comment: Glad I was able to help! Don't for get to mark the answer as correct.